# Publishing a game based on a famous movie to AppStore

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, game-development, rights

Is it allowed to publish a game(or app) based on a famous movie, in which are used real photos of the actors? Will it be rejected because of some author rights issues (US territory) ? If yes, what modifications should be made in order to get approved? 
I ready looked for this information on apple’s website but could’t find anything related.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a legal question not a programming question and the answer will vary between jurisdictions and countries.

Comment: @RoboticCat Then where I should post questions like this?

Comment: I'll suggest https://law.stackexchange.com/